# Best way to store wallet private key in code?

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript, private-key, smart-contract-wallets

I'm using web3.js to interact with my smart contract and I need to save my private key in my js code so that I don't have to be constantly asked to approve a transaction.

I'm using the signTransaction and sendSignedTransaction methods.

What is the best way to store the private key since js code can be seen on the browser?

I'm coding using PHP/JS/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to create multiple points of failure and only create it at runtime. To start with, you can divide your key in 4 parts, store each part in a different keystore (you can use AWS, Microsoft etc.) and only merge them at runtime. It is highly unlikely that all of them will fail at once.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that your code is going to be executed in a browser.

If it is absolutely necessary to use your private key, you will need to build a backend, which does the signing of transactions for you. Depending on where you are hosting your backend, there are services which you could use to protect your private key - KMS is one such service at AWS